# Does Disk Defragmenter run if schedule is missed?

Tags: windows-7, defragment, task-scheduler

I'm reading a Microsoft book which says:

> Disk Defragmenter runs automatically on a schedule in Windows 7 (every
>   Wednesday at 1 a.m.).

What happens if the computer is not powered on at 1 a.m. on a Wednesday?

Does defragmenter run when the computer is next powered on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the surprising initiative to actually check the scheduled task.

Scheduled tasks include an option to "Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled task is missed".

[image]

I think this answers my question.